# Create five copies of file with the same inode number

Tags: files, hard-link, inode

How can I create five copies of `/etc/profile` with the same inode number?

Answer (score 2):

Create hard links.

For example :

```
sudo ln /etc/profile /etc/new_prof
```

Now `/etc/new_prof` and `/etc/profile` both will have the same inode number :

```
$ ls -li /etc/*prof*
3014852 -rw-r--r-- 3 root root  665 Aug 20  2013 /etc/new_prof
3014852 -rw-r--r-- 3 root root  665 Aug 20  2013 /etc/profile
```

Comment: Confirm afterwards by using `ls -li /etc/profile /etc/new_prof` to display inode numbers.

Comment: @steve clarified..